# Get URI for image on ASP.NET server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, uri

I need to load a png stored in my asp.net mvc project into my program as a bitmap image. However, the constructor for BitmapImage only takes a Uri object. How can I access the image?

Doing something like

```
new Uri(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~\\Content\\image.png"))
```

tells me that the format of the URI could not be determined. However it works if I hard code the path (C:\\...etc.)

Comment: MapPath:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would likely want to Map the relative path that you have to the physical path on the server, to do that you can use Server.MapPath();

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As Stefan pointed out, you can use the [MapPath method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx).

```
new Uri(Server.MapPath("~/Content/image.png"))
```